# how can python socket clients have an arbitrary IP while running on one host?

Tags: python, sockets

I'm trying to learn something about socket programming in python.
I have written a server which identifies clients first by their IPs , I want to test the program on localhost, but have no idea how to give different IPs to clients. As I know when we use connect() method, we only specify the host and port of the destination, but what if we want to choose ours?! is there any way?

```
HOST = '127.0.0.1'
PORT = 8018
TIMEOUT = 5
BUF_SIZE = 1024


class WhatsUpClient():

    def __init__(self, host=HOST, port=PORT):
        self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.sock.connect((host, port))
        logging.info('Connecting to %s:%s' % (host, port))
        while 1:
            try:
                buf = self.sock.recv(BUF_SIZE)
                sys.stdout.write(buf)
                cmd = raw_input()
                if cmd.strip() == '!q':
                    sys.exit(1)
                self.sock.send(cmd)
            except:
                self.sock.close()

    def run(self):
        pass
```

Comment: An IP address is assigned to a *computer*, not to a certain *program*. You might want to read about the Internet Protocol on Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Protocol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An IP address needs to be unique for the whole world (with a few exceptions), so you can't arbitrarily pick one and use it.

You can look at is [private networks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network) (192.168.x.x and 10.x.x.x). The easiest way to set this up is to install a virtual machine (like [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/)) on your computer. When you look at the active network interfaces, you'll see that the VM added a few virtual network cards.

If you run your client on the virtual PC, it will get a special, private IP address.

You could also rent a PC in the cloud and run your code there but that costs money.

Another option is to ask your system administrator whether they have any free IP addresses which you can use for testing but usually they don't or they don't want to tell you since it's a bit complicated to set this up.